# Run each command for each module in maven

Tags: maven-2

In multi-moudle project if we type 'mvn clean install', Maven will run both command for each module. Can we run each command for all module and then run next command for all module??

Current:

Building module-1
   task-segment: [clean,install]

Building module-2
   task-segment: [clean,install]

...

Expected:

Building module-1
   task-segment: [clean]

Building module-2
   task-segment: [clean]
...

Building module-1
   task-segment: [install]

Building module-2
   task-segment: [install]
....

Can we achieve this???

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't achieve that, because `mvn clean install` is only **one** command, but with 2 goals.

Your only solution for that is to run `run clean`, *then* `mvn install`.

Comment: Or `mvn clean && mvn install` in a linux shell. Just a shorthand. +1